# Jest import module, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utf16le')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to test a React component with Jest that imports a module called "Siwe", which is sign in with Ethereum.

My Jest config looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "module_name_(.*)":
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/apg-js/src/apg-conv-api/transformers.js",
  },
  transform: {
    "\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest",
  },
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@wagmi)/"'],
};
```

My test code imports a react component, which has the following import:

```
import { SiweMessage } from "siwe";
```

If I remove the import, the test runs fine, but leaving the import in I get an error with the following stack trace

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utf16le')

  18 | import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
  19 | import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
> 20 | import { SiweMessage } from "siwe";
     | ^
  21 |
  22 | type Props = {};
  23 |

  at Object.utf16le [as decode] (node_modules/apg-js/src/apg-conv-api/transformers.js:801:21)
  at decode (node_modules/apg-js/src/apg-conv-api/converter.js:380:27)
  at Object.decode (node_modules/apg-js/src/apg-conv-api/converter.js:391:10)
  at new decode (node_modules/apg-js/src/apg-api/api.js:327:28)
  at Function.generateApi (node_modules/@spruceid/siwe-parser/dist/abnf.js:154:21)
  at Object.generateApi (node_modules/@spruceid/siwe-parser/dist/abnf.js:166:28)
  at Object.require (node_modules/@spruceid/siwe-parser/dist/parsers.js:18:16)
  at Object.require (node_modules/siwe/dist/client.js:37:23)
  at Object.require (node_modules/siwe/dist/siwe.js:17:14)
  at Object.<anonymous> (pages/playground.page.tsx:20:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/playground.test.tsx:2:1)
```

For th life of me, I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Can you share your package.json? Also, do you use some form of bundler?

Answer (score 1):

Module `node_modules/apg-js/src/apg-conv-api/transformers.js` goes through jest's transformer. Jest wraps code in self executed functions that break `apg-conv-api/transformers.js` because it relies on correct [`this` reference inside the module](https://github.com/ldthomas/apg-js/blob/main/src/apg-conv-api/transformers.js#L801).

But the root problem in incorrect `transformIgnorePatterns` as I guess you want to ignore transform for **all** node_modules except `@wagmi` if yes just replace it to:

```json
{
  ...
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@wagmi/)'],
}
```